# How can I obtain the Secret Victories emblem?

Tags: destiny-2

I am working on my [Destinations: Forsaken badge](https://www.light.gg/db/legend/498211331/badges/2881240068/destinations-forsaken/) and I am one item short.

The item in question is the [Secret Victories emblem](https://www.light.gg/db/items/3352019292/secret-victories/). Which states the objective is

> **Objectives**
>   Ascendant chests looted: 1

I have collected all the ascendant chests in the Dreaming City during the highest curse earning me the [War Chests Triumph](https://www.light.gg/db/legend/triumphs/3675740698/war-chests/), without getting this emblem.

What do I have to do to earn this emblem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/9kivjs/secret_victories_emblem/), it can be found from blind well completions.  Any level should do, though most anecdotal evidence shows level II might give the best chance for the emblem (though this has not been confirmed by Bungie).

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/9upl5c/secret_victories_emblem_farming_guide/) also notes that you can get it from ascendant trial chests, though the drop rate is very low.

You will also be granted the base emblem if you manage to get one of the variants by either:

1. Completing all of the ascendant trial time trials or
2. Getting a very rare drop from the heroic blind well bosses

Comment: Blind Well Tier 3 yielded this emblem for me this morning, from the completion chest.

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer get "secret victories" by earning "drink at the well" or from completing the transcendent challenges. As of patch v2.8.0 you must earn all emblems seperately.